# Rest Service Endpoint design: why use multiple keys?

Tags: c#, rest

Say, my data is structured/stored in the following way

```
Account (Id)
     Person Id (Person Details)
```

Should I design my rest service `GET` url so that it requires Account Id as well to retrieve the Person Details?  Example:  `Account/{AccountId}/Person/{PersonId}`

I'm of the view that the url should take minimum number of parameters that is required to retrieve the person details.  In which case Person Id can get what I need.  What I can't understand is in what scenario one would include both IDs.  Why would one pick `Account/Account/{AccountId}/Person/{PersonId}` over `Person/{PersonId}` and vice-versa?

Comment: Opinionated questions are off-topic on SO. As you are pretty much saying yourself, this comes down to personal taste, so there's not really any "right answer" to this.

Comment: i agree with the previous speaker. as a small tip:
here is a really great site to learn how a restful api should be built:
https://swapi.dev/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route `Account/{AccountId}/Person/{PersonId}` might typically be used if the `Person` only made sense in the context of the `Account` (think page of a book). This might mean that the ID of the `Person` would not be unique and formed part of a composite key with the account ID. So if this were the case unless you passed both the `AccountId` and the `PersonId` you could not identify a single unique instance of an entity.

If however the `Person` is an entity in its own right then the `Person/{PersonId}` route would be preferable as it makes consuming the API easier (you don't have to fetch the account ID prior to fetching the person ID). You may feel that you want to ensure that the consumer knows the Account ID prior to the fetching the Person but that would seem to be better dealt with in the authentication/authorisation process rather than in the design of your API endpoints.